# Do we need multithreading for facebook chatbot server?

Tags: multithreading, facebook, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-webhooks

We are working on a facebook chatbot. It looks facebook sends bunch of messages together in a json array and waits until that request is processed. It looks like at least in development phase it does not make multiple web request to server. So do I need to consider multi threading or any other strategy to serve concurrent user?

Example response:

```
{
  "object":"page",
  "entry":[
    {
      "id":"PAGE_ID",
      "time":1458692752478,
      "messaging":[
        {
          "sender":{
            "id":"USER_ID"
          },
          "recipient":{
            "id":"PAGE_ID"
          },

          ...
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Instead multithreading I recommend sticking with concurrency. It is good to use at least an event driven language or a language which handles concurrency without pain.